# dropzone: display current filename during upload

Tags: javascript, jquery, dropzone.js

i want to display the current filename while uploading multiple files with dropzone.js with the following code:

```
dropzone.on("uploadprogress", function(file, parameter, bytes){

  //update progressbar, that works              
  $('#progress').css("width", parameter + "%").html(parseInt(parameter) + " %");     

  //prints the correct filenames
  console.log(file.name);

  //does not work: only last file.name in queue is shown, 
  //even in a real server environment where i upload many files
  $('#currentFile').html(file.name);         

});
```

html:

```
<div class="progress-bar" id="progress"/></div>              
<span id="currentFile"></span>
```

how is it done, that currentFile is really matching the current uploaded file? Thanks in advance.

Comment: as far as i know, you can not change <input type="file" /> value from dom due to security reasons. in order to show file names you have to implement another div to show uploaded files.

Comment: hm - but i don't change <input type="file">; the span '#currentFile' has just a display function. the upload itself is in another div.

Comment: maybe try this : http://www.dropzonejs.com/#event-sending

Comment: Let's see if I understand correctly, do you want to upload one file at a time and display the name and progress of the file being uploaded at that time? Note that for small files you almost only will see the last one. It has nothing to do with the input btw.

Comment: sambe behaviour for sending-event; all file names are shown in the console but currentFile never gets updated and always keeps the last filename in queue. i have configured dropzone with "uploadMultiple: true": same effect when i upload 10 files on my server at a time, each with a filesize of 5 MB (while the progressbar moves slowly forward)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code should work just fine, the only problem I see is that dropzone uploads the files simultaneously, what can make your display to switch between the different files really fast, because the `uploadProgress` event triggers independently for all the files being uploaded, and this can overlap with one and other, this can cause that you only see the data for the last file being upload.

The only solution I can think of is to make dropzone upload one file at a time, I am assuming you start the upload process manually, with `autoProcessQueue` set to `false`, here an example:

```
Dropzone.options.myDropzone = {
    url: 'yourUrl',
    autoProcessQueue: false,
    parallelUploads: 1,
    init: function() {
        var mydrop = this; // Closure

        // This is the event listener that triggers the start of the upload
        $('#yourSubmitButtonId').on('click', function(){
            mydrop.processQueue();
        });

        this.on('success', function(file){

            // Just to see default server response on console
            console.log(file.xhr.responseText);

            // Continue processing the queue if there are still files pending
            if (this.getQueuedFiles().length > 0) {
                this.processQueue();
            } else {
                console.log('Job done');
            }

        });

        this.on('uploadprogress', function(file, parameter, bytes){

          //update progressbar, that works              
          $('#progress').css("width", parameter + "%").html(parseInt(parameter) + " %");     

          //prints the correct filenames
          console.log(file.name);

          //does not work: only last file.name in queue is shown, 
          //even in a real server environment where i upload many files
          $('#currentFile').html(file.name);         

        });  
    }
};
```

Comment: thank you for you explanation which sounds conclusive. i had something like that in mind. it indeed works as expected when uploading only one file a time. but i have the requirement to upload all chosen files once, because there is no need for our users to upload each file separately.

Comment: Even the upload is done one at a time, the feel for the user is going to be the same that if all were uploaded at once. What you need to do in this case is put together again all the files in server side. Otherwise I don't think its possible to accomplish the behavior that you want with dropzone.

Comment: oh sorry, i misunderstood a little bit. with your above code,  of course i can upload multiple files at once, but for each file a new server-communication is made. got it.  well, your suggestion works and i will use it for now. thanks.